# pandas change nan value from a column to first letters of string of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to change values of a column if it is null, by the first letters of a string split by spaces from another column of a DataFrame:

```
          A                             B
0       NaN  Column To Pick First Letters
1  GoodToGo                     Something
```

Would result in:

```
          A                             B
0     CTPFL  Column To Pick First Letters
1  GoodToGo                     Something
```

So far I only managed to use `df['A'] = filnan(value=df['B'])`, but it copies the whole string of the column B, using split gives me a split of all the values in column B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` the strings then reshape into a single Series, grab the first letter and use `groupby` + `str.join` to create the string. Then `fillna` to only change the `NaN` values.

```
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B'].str.split(expand=True).stack().str[0].groupby(level=0).agg(''.join))
```

---

```
          A                             B
0     CTPFL  Column To Pick First Letters
1  GoodToGo                     Something
```

---

To break it down a little, the split and stack creates a Series of separate words, with the 0th level of the index pointing to the orignal row-label.

```
df['B'].str.split(expand=True).stack()
#0  0       Column
#   1           To
#   2         Pick
#   3        First
#   4      Letters
#1  0    Something
```

With the `.str` accessor we can grab the first letter for each value in this Series.

```
df['B'].str.split(expand=True).stack()
#0  0    C
#   1    T
#   2    P
#   3    F
#   4    L
#1  0    S
```

And now we group over the 0th level (original row Index) to join the first letters.

```
df['B'].str.split(expand=True).stack().str[0].groupby(level=0).agg(''.join)
#0    CTPFL
#1        S
```

This Series is what is then used to `fillna`

Comment: tx defnitely above my pedigree!